# Java Buffered Input Stream not reading

Tags: java

I am having issues trying to figure out buffered input streams. We are having to create a text editor program in Java. I have a few examples from class as a guideline but still have not been able to figure it out. From my understanding I have primed the loop with a read, then it should read the entire file into the editor. I have typecasted the read as a char then set it to a string using .toString. Now it compiles, but freezes the program, so i must have an endless loop, but am unsure why.

```
        //File open
    openItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser();
        jfc.setCurrentDirectory(new File("."));
        int result = jfc.showOpenDialog(null);
        if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
            {
            File selectedFile = jfc.getSelectedFile();
            BufferedInputStream bis = null;
            try
            {
                bis = new BufferedInputStream( new FileInputStream(selectedFile) );
                char inChar = (char)bis.read();
                while(inChar != -1)
                {
                //inChar = (char)bis.read();
                String charToString = Character.toString(inChar);
                textArea.setText(charToString);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e2)
            {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: you are reading the file char by char, overwriting the contents of the field every loop.

Comment: @MattClark Considering that the line which reads the char inside the loop is commented out, the file is not being read at all

Comment: you are correct. `String string=""; while (( inChar = (char)bis.read()) != -1 ){string+=inChar;} System.out.println(string);`

Comment: after applying that logic, the program still freezes up when i run it, could it be happening since i have not closed the buffered input stream bis?

Comment: @davidbrown This happens because you are reading the file in the UI thread. You should create another thread or use a [SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for that purpose.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems here.

**Problem 1**: [`BufferedInputStream#read()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html#read--) reads bytes, not chars.  It will produce results that "work" for ASCII streams, but will fail for other multibyte encodings such as UTF-8.

**Problem 2**: `char` values are unsigned in Java, so the expression `inChar != -1` will always be true.  I think this is what is causing your application to freeze.

**Problem 3**: You are not closing the file after using it.

As the general operation of reading file contents as a `String` might be a useful thing elsewhere in your code, it may be worth considering implementing this functionality as a separate method.

If you wanted to maintain the current structure, code like the following should work, but **still has problem 1**.

```
public static String readFileAsString(File inputFile) throws IOException {
  try (BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(inputFile))) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int in = bis.read(); in != -1; in = bis.read()) {
      sb.append((char)in);
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }
}
```

There are easier ways to read an entire file as a `String` with Java.  One possibility with Java8 is something like this:

```
public static String readFileAsString(File inputFile) throws IOException {
  return new String(Files.readAllBytes(inputFile.toPath()));
}
```

Which uses the default charset to convert bytes to characters.

Comment: or `new String (readbytes_result, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)` reliably gives the same conversion as the cast-int-containing-byte-to-char approach -- which as you note may or may not be the desired one.